# I am getting error on this line in my code

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am still developing my School management system. I want  to create a multiple username and password for my  system. But I am getting a Runt ime error 31314 on the Insert statement.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO users(Username,Password,Email,Mobile,UserType) VALUES('" & Me.uname & "', '" & Me.upass & "', '" & Me.uemail & "', '" & Me.umobile & "', '" & Me.utype & "',)"
```

Comment: Are all of your fields text fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can/should use a temporary parameter query:

- The sql statement looks much more clear
- It takes care of datatypes (no `'`s necessary)
- It prevents SQL Injection

```
With CurrentDb().CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, _
        "INSERT INTO users (Username, [Password], Email, Mobile, UserType) VALUES (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)")
    .Parameters("p1").Value = Me.uname
    .Parameters("p2").Value = Me.upass
    .Parameters("p3").Value = Me.uemail
    .Parameters("p4").Value = Me.umobile
    .Parameters("p5").Value = Me.utype
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```

If you want you can rename the parameters `p1` to `p5` to more describing names i.e. `pUName` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing comma here:

```vb
"INSERT INTO users(Username,Password,Email,Mobile,UserType) VALUES('" & ... & Me.utype & "',)"
Trailing commma ---------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You should also surround the `Password` field with square brackets, since this is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in MS Access:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (Username, [Password], Email, Mobile, UserType)
```